# No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a executable jar file with Eclipse from my Spring Boot application. The plugin I have in my pom.xml is below

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <mainClass>nl.insiteweb.acc.Application</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

The complete error I get is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [nl.insiteweb.acc.Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:520) ~[testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184) ~[testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308) ~[testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [testproject.jar:na]
    at nl.insiteweb.acc.Application.main(Application.java:16) [testproject.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:276) ~[testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getCandidateConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:152) ~[testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:94) ~[testproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:512) ~[testproject.jar:na]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Im trying to make a executable JAR file with the Export within Eclipse. All help is much appreciated.